# Azure Charging for SQL Databases for push in mobile services

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure for push notifications in my app. For creating a mobile service it requires SQL database that is created inside it and for SQL database i have been charged around 3.5 $/month. But when I open that database , Nothing is inside it. The question is why I would need a database for this service ?
If it is not in Use , Can I Delete it , So that I cannot be charged for it.

Comment: This question is off-topic. Please ask the Azure Support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Azure Mobile Services but don't use the tables features, you can safely delete the associated database.

You can also create a notification hub directly and not use a mobile service, if you'd prefer.